# How to stop demonize version of spamd

Tags: spamassassin

Recently I've been using the daemon version of spamassassin (spamd) in Centos.

In some circumstances I need to stop the daemon. What is the best way to do that?

I'm used to stopping the mailserver first and then issuing `kill -15 spamd` but I don't know if this is ok.

Comment: Search the */etc/init.d* directory for a start/kill script related to spamassasin or spamd.  Just a guess, but you might be able to use something like `sudo /etc/init.d/spamd stop`  This would utilize the same procedure that an ordinary system shutdown would perform.

Comment: Thx dude, just i forgot to mention that spamd was installed from source and /etc/init.d/spamd dosen't exists .

Answer (score 1):

Log in SSH as root and run:

`/scripts/spamassassindisable`

Today I was having trouble with spamd and needed to stop it in order to find out what was going on in my VPS and found somewhere only how to restart it, it was inside /scripts and it started with spam[something]. So I just found spamassassindisable and bang!, it was exactly what I needed. The command name itself is auto-explainable!

Comment: Why the downvote if it precisely answers the question?

Comment: You don’t even indicate what the script does.  It might be obvious, but, I wonder the reason nobody knows about the script in over 6 years.

Comment: @Heitor, no good deed goes unpunished.  In general, just giving a command with no explanation is viewed as a poor answer, even if it's correct.  The community likes to see answers that educate.  Can you add any meat to the answer (e.g., a sentence on what the command does, link to documentation, etc.).  You've been a site member for almost a year and this is your first post.  Lets see if we can get you a little positive rep.  :-)

Comment: I'm a member of Stack Exchange's websites for a long time, mostly StackOverflow. Today I was having trouble with spamd and needed to stop it in order to find out what was going on in my VPS and found somewhere only how to restart it, it was inside /scripts and it started with spam[something]. I just found spamassassindisable and bang, it was exactly what I needed. The command name itself is so self explainable...the guy who downvoted just saw and old question without answers and just downvoted a precise, concise and correct answer from somebody with no reputatin in SuperUser...

Comment: I'm sure that was automatic, just to sum a couple of points in his/her score...hey, look that, it's some meat for my answer haha!